# maximum recursion depth exceeded and how to make script more efficient

Tags: python, recursion

I'm creating a script using this library: https://github.com/oczkers/fut14

However, after some time, I get the error "maximum recursion depth exceeded." Afterwards I did some research and saw that I could increase this, however I would like to know a better way of avoiding this error and making my script more efficient.

```
def search():
items = fut.searchAuctions('player', level='gold', max_buy=250, start=0, page_size=15)
print (items)
if items == 1:
    print (buy_now_price)
    print (trade_id)
    fut.bid(items[0]['trade_id'], 'buy_now_price')
elif items == 0:
    search()
```

Answer (score 2):

Most python installation only allow you to recurse 1000 levels (Python's self-imposed artificial limit).

A new "recursion level" happens every time your function `search` calls itself and involves saving some information of each function call on top of the stack. Once this stack has "grown" tall enough, you receive a "maximum recursion depth exceeded." also known as a stack overflow :).

You can modify your recursive algorithm to an iterative one instead to avoid this.

See [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration) for an algorithmic way to convert from a recursive function to an iterative one. It involves using a list to simulate a stack (a list can grow much larger than Python's stack).

### Recursive to iterative example

Although using the algorithmic way to convert a recursive to iterative function works, it's not the best approach since you are still using a growing list to represent your stack. Sometimes you can analyze your algorithm and find a way rewrite your algorithm without simulating any stack.

In your example, it seems that you simply want a function that will run forever until it finds something. You can rewrite it iteratively as follows

```
def search():
    while True:
        items = fut.searchAuctions('player', level='gold', max_buy=250, start=0, page_size=15
        print (items)
        if items == 1:
           break

    print (buy_now_price)
    print (trade_id)
    fut.bid(items[0]['trade_id'], 'buy_now_price')
```